# How to replace the second match of a string of token using \patchcmd?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, paragraphs, etoolbox, patching

I will first raise a general question and then try to describe what I actually want to achieve.

### General question: How to patch the match other than the first one using `\patchcmd`

The logic of the command `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` is basically a search and replace procedure. But, in the manual, it explicitly said that

> matches the **first** occurence of the <search> pattern in the replacement text of the <command> to be patched

Then, my question is how to replace the second match, the third match, or maybe all the matches. The reason for this is that many built-in commands of latex have the following structure

```
\ifxxx
<some commands>
\theComandIWantToReplace
<some commands>
\else
<some other commands>
\theComandIWantToReplace
<some other commands>
\fi
```

And according to my practice, by using `\patchcmd` I cannot replace the second case.

### More specific: How to add a paragraph symbol to the TOC item and bookmark of the paragraph

To be more specific, what I want to achieve is to add a paragraph symbol to the `\paragraph` item in the ToC and also the PDF bookmark. After some searches using `latexdef`, I find that the economiest way is to just patch the `\addcontentsline` command inside the `\paragraph` command and so I try

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\paragraph}{\addcontentsline {toc}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else \protect \numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}}{\addcontentsline {toc}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else \protect \numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi\P~#7}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \paragraph{asdadas}
\end{document}
```

**Notice that I have added a `\P`** to the replaced text. But it seems not to produce the desired results. I guess the reason to be the fact that the search command actually appear twice in the `\paragraph` command as
[image]

But, there is high chance that I'm wrong.

### System info

If that matters, I'm using TexLive 2021 on a MacOS 12.3.1 and compile using pdflatex.

Comment: for your general question: patch to replace the first match with "XXXXXX", then patch to replace the second match with your code, then patch to replace the XXXXXX with the original code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much, I understand!

Answer (score 1):

The patch is unsuccessful, because the search text is *not* in the replacement text for `\paragraph`.

And you don't want to patch `\@sect` either, because this would affect every sectioning command.

Just redefine `\theparagraph`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\bookmarksetup{level=4,numbered}

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\P~\thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\paragraph{asdadas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a brilliant method! But here is some other obstacle. Actually, I define a new command, which behaves quite differently from the traditional `\paragraph` so that I have to write it from the scratch but can not patch the `\paragraph` command. But, in human logic, I treat this new command the same as a `\paragraph` and want to add a TOC line and also the corresponding bookmark every time this new command is called.

Comment: Currently, I add the following line in the definition of this new command to realize this functionality `\addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{#1}` with `#1` efficiently serving as the paragraph name. Combined with this counter redefinition method, the TOC of this new command behaves fine, ie, the `\P` mark shows up correctly. But in the bookmark, there is no such symbol. I have tried to modify this command to be `\addcontentsline{toc}{paragraph}{\P~#1}`. In this way, the bookmark is now fine but in the TOC there will be two `\P` symbols showing up. Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: @QiTianluo Without seeing your redefinition of `\paragraph`, nobody can help.